# Calling a WCF service with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

Trying to figure out why I can't talk to my WCF service using jQuery, I created a parameterless method called Hello that returns a string "hi".

A WinForms test client invokes it successfully, and here is the request that Fiddler captured:

```
POST http://wone.zapto.org/FX2/FxService.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPowVZ+FU0+uNPsqYRI526N4sAAAAA8cdbBjT1DEK5yC+TNqcV7MkOd0n0tatAltu9uJjPIqUACQAA
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IFxService/Hello"
Host: wone.zapto.org
Content-Length: 130
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><Hello xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

This is XML, not JSON. The response was also XML and contained the expected value "hi".

This is the service interface method declaration:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Hello();
```

Going on my results this is clearly *not* how you make the method compatible with jQuery ajax calls.

How can I do one of the following?

1. Configure the service to be compatible to jQuery
2. Get jQuery to make a call that's compatible with the service as it currently stands?

I know this can be done; we did it at my last job, but unfortunately I can't simply examine the code any more.

---

My WCF book says it should be

```
[OperationContract, WebGet]
string Hello();
```

but after recompiling and redeploying and retesting there is no change, it's all still XML.

Comment: I believe this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901695/calling-a-winform-hosted-wcf-service-from-javascript

might help you out

Comment: @Zach - As required by Murphy's Law you have cracked it 30 seconds after I discovered that if I add a WCF service to the web that will use it, rather than building a separate WCF service application, what I get is all but ready to use and full of instructive comments that led directly to a successful test. Thanks anyway for trying to help, it's greatly appreciated.